# Remove points partimat plot in R

Tags: r, points, lda

I produced a plot with the partimat function on R. [image: Partima Plot]
   However, the data points on the picture are ruining the plot. Is there anyway to keep the boundaries and to remove the points from the image? Also, I would like to add a legend to associate each number with it's color.

Here is the code:

```
    library(ElemStatLearn);
    data(zip.train);
    load(zip.train);
    zipTrain=data.frame(zip.train);
    x=zipTrain[,-1];
    y=zipTrain[,1];
    library(MASS)
    model=lda(y~.,data=x)
    projected.data=as.matrix(x)%*%as.matrix(model$scaling)
    projected.data=as.data.frame(projected.data)
   M1=projected.data

couleurs=c("aquamarine","blue","brown","chartreuse","cyan","darkgreen","darkorange","pink","gold","gray") 
   library(klaR) 
   Matrice=data.frame(X2=M1[,2],X1=M1[,1],Y=y)
   partimat(x=Matrice[,-3], grouping=as.factor(Matrice[,3]), method="lda", 
  col.mean="gold", image.colors =couleurs,pre=200,display.points=FALSE)
```

Comment: `col.correct=NA, col.wrong=NA` seems to be one way ...

Comment: @user20650 Thank you! Do you have any idea of a simple way to place an image of a choosen number somewhere on the plot?

Comment: Infact try `gs=NA` . You mean like this either `points(4,0, pch=16, cex=10) ; ` or `text(4, 0, "A", col="red")`

Comment: The second one is the one that I need. Thank you!